# JMockit: show obscure error message about missing invocation 1 to error

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dependencies, jmockit

I have to test a class `UserAdmin` whose dependency is on a database class. I have mocked the database class to test the `UserAdmin` class. The database class has a method `isAdmin()` which decides if the user is the administrator or not. The `UserAdmin` class has a method called `removeUser()` for which I am getting this error. the `removeUser()` method does not allow to remove the user if the user is an Admin
Following is the code for which I am seeing this error.

```
@Test
    //testing remove user method of UserAdmin - remove Admin
        public void testremoveUserAdmin() throws SQLException{
            new Expectations() {{
                
                dBConnection.isAdmin("admin");
                times=1;
                result = true;
                
            }};             
         assertEquals(false,userAdmin.removeUser("admin"));
```

When I put the above `assertEquals()`, it gives a missing invocation error but when I replace false with true in the assertion, it says expected was true but it was false. I am not sure where why I am getting this error. A similar code run for similar methods like `isAdmin()` worked fine. Please help

Comment: How are you declaring the "dBConnection" field? With `@Mocked` or `@Injectable`? If it's the second, then this same mocked instance must be the one used inside the `UserAdmin#removeUser` method.

Comment: I have used @Mocked
 DBConnection dBConnection;

Comment: When I put the above assertequals, it gives a missing invocation error but when I replace false with true in the assertion, it says expected was true but it was false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
public class UserAdminTest {
    static class DBConnection { boolean isAdmin(String userName) { return false; } }

    static class UserAdmin {
        boolean removeUser(String userName) {
            DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();

            if (!dbConnection.isAdmin(userName)) {
                // remove user
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    @Tested UserAdmin userAdmin;
    @Mocked DBConnection dBConnection;

    @Test
    public void doesNotRemoveUserWhenAdmin() throws Exception {
        new Expectations() {{ dBConnection.isAdmin("admin"); result = true; }};

        boolean removedIt = userAdmin.removeUser("admin");

        assertFalse(removedIt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Rogerio. The same @Test part is what I wrote and it worked.!

Answer (score 0):

There was another method that should have been called before the isAdmin method. Calling it before the isAdmin method solved the problem.

Comment: I have exact same problem. How did you fix it? There is invocation in my method so I put it in expectations but it looks like what i declare in expectations never gets invoked.